# Word similar to relief, on the tip of my tongue

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to think of a word that would be used to describe the only relief out of a bad scenario, kind of like the silver lining, of the only redeeming quality of a ln unfortunate event.

Example: *description of the bad event* "my only ______ was that the phone didn't completely break"

I initially was going to write "solstice" but my brain kicked in and realized that's not the meaning of that word at all, but maybe the actual word sounds similar to "solstice".

Comment: AH thank you, that was going to bother me for the rest of the evening. I was close, but not quite there haha

Comment: way to remember it: James Bond's Quantum of Solace

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.

Answer (score 6):

You're thinking of solace: "comfort in sorrow, misfortune, or trouble; alleviation of distress or discomfort." (source: dictionary.com)

1250-1300; Middle English solas < Old French < Latin sōlācium, equivalent to sōl (ārī) to comfort + -āc- adj. suffix + -ium -ium

Answer (score 1):

Not the word you were actually thinking of, apparently, but in that sentence I would be more likely to use ***[consolation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consolation)***:

> something that makes a person feel less sadness, disappointment, etc.
>   <sub>*definition from [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consolation)*</sub>